# ¿Cómo recorrer objetos TextBox en bucle `for`?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy buscando realizar una función muy parecida o igual a la que se usa en `Javascript`, en el cual pueda recorrer los objetos por el tipo de elemento que es, y de esa manera aplicarles un `set` o un `get` mientras los va recorriendo. Pero en `C#` no sé si exista dicha funcionalidad. Ejemplo en `Javascript` :

```
for(var i = 0; i < $('input').length; i++){
      var name_input = $('input')[i].getAttribute('name');
    }
```

Esto lo que hace es que encuentra todos mis elementos de tipo `input`, los va recorriendo y al mismo tiempo obteniendo su atributo `name`. No sé si en `C# Windows forms` exista una manera de hacerlo, que reconozca los tipos de elementos y los recorra. 
Me funcionó al hacer un `array` de tipo `object`, y le metí manualmente los controles para recorrerlos en el `for`, y sí funcionó. Pero me parece mejor que sea dinámico y encuentre los elementos automáticamente sin la necesidad de crear dicho `array`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente

1) Primero identifica el control que contiene los textbox , puede ser un panel o estar en el mismo formulario.

```
foreach (ctrl in [form-o-panel].Controls){

    if (ctrl is textbox){

      //Tu lógica aca usando el objecto ctrl
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 1):

Ya te respondieron, pero te voy a dar otra opción, usando Linq:

```
foreach(var textBox in formulario.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    // aquí puedes modificar o usar la variable textBox 
}
```

Y si lo quieres aun mas funcional y declarativo:

```
formulario.Controls
    .OfType<TextBox>()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(textBox => {
        // Aquí usas la variable textBox para modificarla
    });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo tendré en cuenta también.

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma de hacerlo:

En el caso de tener los controles en un grid:
en el xaml le asignas un nombre: Grid x:Name="grid1"

Y en c# recorres la lista con grid1.Children

Código:

```
        foreach (Control  b in grid1.Children)
        {
         if(b is Button  )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("soy un boton");
            }                

            else if(b is TextBox){
                MessageBox.Show("soy textbox");
            }

         else if(b is ListBox)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("soy listbox");
            }
        }
```